# how clean up pattern matching expression (or how to use exisential types as constrained class and specific type.)

Tags: haskell

consider

```
data Foo1 = Foo1 { f1 :: Int }
data Foo2 = Foo2 { f2 :: Int }
data Foo3 = Foo3 { f3 :: Int }

data Thing = 
    Thing1 Foo1
  | Thing2 Foo2
  | Thnig3 Foo3

bar :: Thing -> Int
bar (Thing1 foo1) = f1 foo1
bar (Thing2 foo2) = f2 foo2
..
```

this is clearly insane.

how can i fix this?

i tried

```
class Foo g where
  f :: g -> Int

instance Foo (Foo1) where
  f = f1
...
```

but this doesn't event help, as i still can't write `bar` without all the pattern matching.

what i *want* is

```
bar :: Thing -> Int
bar (_ foo) = f foo
```

but this isn't possible.

(i could paramaterise Thing by the type of foo, and then it would work fine; but i can't do that in my actual code; i.e. i need the "Thing" to be totally general. i'm confused as to why i have to do the pattern matching k times for FooK if i've say defined some typeclass that they all work on.)

Comment: Are all the `FooN`s and `ThingN`s the same?  Or are you wanting a more generalized answer?

Comment: no; the ThingN's are just tokens to pattern-match the FooN's which will contain different records per foo. All the foo's will be a `Foo` though; and those are the only things that will be `Foo`s. i just want to write a bunch of code which can operate on any given `Foo` (coming from a `Thing`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a field that you want to usually use existentially but occasionally pattern match on the specific type then you can build a singleton type to recover the existential back into a concrete type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Foo1 = Foo1 { f1 :: Int }
data Foo2 = Foo2 { f2 :: Int }
data Foo3 = Foo3 { f3 :: Int }

class Foo g where
  f :: g -> Int

-- A singleton type which introduces a unique constructor
-- for each type you want to store in the existential.
data SFoo t where
    SFoo1 :: SFoo Foo1
    SFoo2 :: SFoo Foo2
    SFoo3 :: SFoo Foo3

-- The type parameter of the singleton matches with the existential.
-- This allows us to use pattern matching to find out the real type
-- of "t" later on.
data Thing where
    Thing :: Foo t => SFoo t -> t -> Thing

-- Now you can use the existential through the type-class
bar :: Thing -> Int
bar (Thing _ foo) = f foo

-- And you can also pattern match on a specific constructor
-- when needed. Pattern matching on the singleton "SFoo1"
-- convinces the type-checker that the existential field
-- must have a type of "Foo1" which lets you use it normally.
bar2 :: Thing -> Maybe Int
bar2 (Thing SFoo1 (Foo1 i)) = Just i
bar2 _ = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Existentially qualified types to the rescue! Note that this is not part of Haskell98, so you will need to enable one of the GHC type system extensions.

Here, we define `Thing` to be able to hold an object of any type that is an instance of your `Foo` typeclass.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

class Foo g where
  f :: g -> Int

data Foo1 = Foo1 { f1 :: Int }
instance Foo (Foo1) where f = f1

data Thing = forall a . Foo a => Thing a

bar :: Thing -> Int
bar (Thing t) = f t
```

See the "heterogeneous lists" example here:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types

Edit 1:

If you need to be able to extract the particular `FooN` then seems like you'll need to do the pattern match at least once.  One option is to do the pattern match once to construct a generic `FooThing` from a `Thing`, then, when possible, you can use `FooThing`

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

class Foo g where
  f :: g -> Int

data Foo1 = Foo1 { f1 :: Int }
instance Foo (Foo1) where f = f1

data Thing = Thing1 Foo1

data FooThing = forall a . Foo a => FooThing a

fooThing :: Thing -> FooThing
fooThing (Thing1 t) = FooThing t

bar :: Thing -> Int
bar = g . fooThing
  where g (FooThing t) = f t
```

You could even go a step further and define an instance of `Foo` for `Thing`

```
instance Foo (Thing) where
 f = g . fooThing
   where g (FooThing t) = f t
```

Edit 2:

After seeing shang's answer, GADTs are probably a better approach even if you only need to work with a `Thing Foo1` as a ```Foo``, for example

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

class Foo g where
  f :: g -> Int

data Foo1 = Foo1 { f1 :: Int }
instance Foo (Foo1) where f = f1

data Thing where
     Thing :: Foo t => t -> Thing

bar :: Thing -> Int
bar (Thing foo) = f foo
```

Comment: hmm; this doesn't work, because i can now *only* work with a `Thing Foo1` as a `Foo`; but when I have a `Thing Foo1` I also occasionally need to know that it is a `Foo1` in particular .... (hence the `Thing1` to notify that ...); but maybe it can still done this way?